# Add column in database then update the dbml

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an application that have a dynamic table in database. The problem is, let say there's a change in table structure like addition of column, can I update the dbml file dynamically? so I don't have to fix the application everytime the column been added

Comment: How often do these table changes happen?  You can generate the dbml by manually calling [**`SQLMetal`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) from the command-line.

Comment: Well, for these year for example, one of the tables will have 4 columns addition. but it won't come together. any possibilities?

Comment: anyway, can you give some useful link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DBML and code generation approach, no there's no way to let your application take advantage of the changes automagically. The DBML results in new generated code which needs to be compiled, that requires the DSL Toolkit, Visual Studio and the .NET SDK to be present.

Comment: Yes, or use a different approach towards your dynamic extension. Instead of creating a new column or table, can you use a different approach to modelling the data?

Comment: I think I can't because this is for improvement of the app. But, I'll consider your suggest